# Did R. Shlomo Yosef Zevin provide sources for his stories?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, publications, hasidic-story

In a letter to R' Shlomo Yosef Zevin, the Lubavitcher Rebbe asked Rabbi Zevin to include sources for the stories he compiled in his *Sipurei Chassidim*.

You can see parts of the letter (printed in Igerot Kodesh vol 11) quoted [here](http://shturem.net/index.php?section=blog_new&article_id=272&lang=hebrew) (I'm not going to translate it, because it is not relevant to the question):

> "בדורנו מבולבל זה, הנה ככל שיש להבהיר הענינים ולהוסיף דיוק, מועיל הוא ביותר... וה"ה בהנוגע לאוסף סיפורים ע"ד נשיאי ישראל... יש להעיר [=לציין]... מקורו של כל סיפור והעיקר – הסמכות שלו. ואם בהנוגע לכל נשיאי ישראל הדברים אמורים, עאכו"כ לנשיאי תנועת החסידות, אשר ידיעות שאינן מדוייקות ולפעמים ענינים מזויפים וכו' – הביאו נזק רב להפצת תורת החסידות והחדרת הדרכותי' ומנהגי' לחוגים יותר רחבים... כדאי שעכ"פ ידפיס עתה מראה מקום מקור כל סיפור... ומה טוב אם אפשר, לצרף לזה גם שורות אחדות ע"ד ערך הסמכות של קובצי הסיפורים השונים וכן המספרים השונים – שכידוע יש בזה שני הקצוות, היינו בעלי סמכות בתכלית ולהיפך, ורובם נמצאים בין שני הקצוות...
>
> "ישנם סיפורי חסידים המעוררים תמהון, ומסקנת חלק מהשומעים הוא, שבודאי איש פלוני – שאודותיו הסיפור – עשה היפך הדין או עכ"פ היפך הלפנים משוה"ד. וזה פועל גם על יחסם בכלל לנושאי תורת החסידות ולתורת החסידות עצמה. בה בשעה שע"י שינוי קטן באיזה ביטויים אשר בהסיפור, סרה כל התמיה. וכיון דרובא דרובא של הסיפורים עברו דרך כמה צנורות, ודאי הוא אשר הביטויים אינם מדוייקים כ"כ, ובפרט – בהעתק מלשון ללשון...
>
> "ואביא שתי דוגמאות:...
> ב) סיפור שי"ג: אשר הרה"צ ר' משולם זוסיא ציוה לחפור הקבר ולחפש שם כו' – שקשה להצדיק הוראה זו ע"פ שו"ע, משא"כ בשינוי קטן, שהדברים לאו דוקא בהקבר אלא בסביבות שלו או בד' אמות שלו, סרה כל התמיה. ובודאי בהשתלשלות כל הסיפורים לא דייקו כ"כ שזה הקבר ממש – וכפי שיפרשו הקורא בספר

Did R' Zevin include sources for his stories? The English Translation by Artscroll, *A Treasury of Chassidic Tales*, does not have sources, and I don't have access to the Hebrew.

Comment: help with tags, please

Comment: Jews not Judaism?

Comment: @DonielF Huh? Its a question about whether sources were included for a popular Jewish work.

Comment: @mevaqesh But does that make it Judaism? It’s just a story book about Jews.

Comment: @DonielF I realise that, but it Hassidic tales, for better or for worse are part of Jewish literature. If nothing else. we can cite a famous Litvak that "nonsense is nonsense, but the study of nonsense is scholarship." That is, asking about the stories themselves would be off topic, but asking about a book about them would be on topic. That may seem contradictory, but I think it makes sense. You can disagree.

Comment: @mevaqesh I really don’t hear that logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across a copy of ספורי חסידם, and at the end of the volume on festivals, there is a general source page. It lists the sources, but not specific page numbers, or specific sources for individual sources.

I took a picture:

[image: Mekorot 1]  [image: Mekorot 2]

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew original of ספורי חסידים does not include sources.

Occasionally there is a footnote referencing some detail (e.g. story 231) but that is the exception, not the rule.